# How to create custom page with user images in grid and with pagination, not using views

Tags: hooks, theming

As I guess I need to override node.tpl.php or page.tpl.php?

Comment: Views is the standard and easiest way to do this, in order for us to better understand the situation please explain why a view would not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use hook_menu() to create a path to your page. Then use db_select() with the tableSort extender to supply pagination in the hook_menu `page callback`. Select the uid, username, user image(s) ? in your database query.

Then just loop over your resultset and output a div with your user images per cell. Simply float all the divs to the left so your output appears as a grid instead of a single long column of rows.